# Mailgun Send email using RestSharp ExecuteAsync method in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, restsharp, mailgun

I have created a function for send email using RestSharp in VS2010. If I use client.Execute then it works fine, but if I use client.ExecuteAsync then it gives the error.

```
Dim client As New RestSharp.RestClient()
client.BaseUrl = New Uri("URL").ToString()
client.Authenticator = New HttpBasicAuthenticator("test", "test")
Dim request As New RestRequest()

request.AddParameter("from", "test@xyz.com")
request.AddParameter("to", "abc@xyz.com")
request.AddParameter("subject", "Test Email")
request.AddParameter("html", "This is the test email.")
request.Method = Method.POST
client.ExecuteAsync(Request, Sub(res)
                         output_txt.Text = res.Content
                     End Sub)
```

I get the following error:

> Error 92 Overload resolution failed because no accessible
>   'ExecuteAsync' can be called with these arguments: 'Public Overridable
>   Function ExecuteAsync(Of T)(request As RestSharp.IRestRequest,
>   callback As System.Action(Of RestSharp.IRestResponse(Of T),
>   RestSharp.RestRequestAsyncHandle)) As
>   RestSharp.RestRequestAsyncHandle': Type parameter 'T' cannot be
>   inferred. 'Public Overridable Function ExecuteAsync(request As
>   RestSharp.IRestRequest, callback As System.Action(Of
>   RestSharp.IRestResponse, RestSharp.RestRequestAsyncHandle)) As
>   RestSharp.RestRequestAsyncHandle': Nested sub does not have a
>   signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Action(Of
>   RestSharp.IRestResponse, RestSharp.RestRequestAsyncHandle)'. Extension
>   method 'Public Function ExecuteAsync(Of T)(request As
>   RestSharp.IRestRequest, callback As System.Action(Of
>   RestSharp.IRestResponse(Of T))) As RestSharp.RestRequestAsyncHandle'
>   defined in 'RestSharp.RestClientExtensions': Type parameter 'T' cannot
>   be inferred.